# tableau aggregate data based on dimension

Tags: aggregate-functions, aggregate, tableau-api

I am having a problem in Tableau, hopefully someone can help me and
is very much appreciated!!

A simplifiend example of a problem I can't fix in Tableau:

```
Payment   Customer  Amount
1          BMW       20000
2          VW        30000
3          BMW        1000
4          VW         5000
5          VW         6000
```

This has to be aggregated on the Customer level and has to look like this:

```
Customer    Amount
BMW           21000
VW            41000
```

This is for 10.000 customers..

Thanks in advance!

Tim

---

[image: my data]

I want to take the average/mean/max for each year (pool cut-off date)  in order to compare the years.

In R I always saved the new dataframe, but here this seems to be different.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum() is one of Tableau's built-in aggregation functions, so there is no need to write a calculated field if that's all you're doing. Just drag the [Amount] field on to (say) the text shelf and select Sum() as the aggregation. Then put [Customer] on the row shelf.

Sum() is efficient, and performed on the database server only sending back the results to the client. So if you are summing a million rows, only the answer needs to be sent over the wire. Of course, if you are grouping by a dimension so that half your dimension members have only one row, you'll still be sending back lots of data.

If your calculation is more complicated, emh is correct about where to start making calculated fields.

Comment: Thanks!THis is it. Is it also possible to save this as a measure? I need to do calculations with it. I have to calculate how many percent this is of the maximum outstanding credit. This is a number given per customer. So for example bmw has a maximum outstanding credit of 100.000 and thus the ratio that needs to be calculated is 21%. (21k/100k) Thanks Alex

Comment: Then the calculated field you create could be as simple as "Sum(Amount) / Max(Credit_Available)" assuming there is a field called Credit_Available. In this case, Credit_Available should be the same for each row in the data that has the same value for the Customer field. That's typical if its joined in from a another table.

Comment: OK thanks, that does the trick per borrowerID. Now I am trying to get the average of all borrwerID's. For this example that would be:           (0.21 + 0.82)/2 = 0.515 or a weighted value: (21k+41k)/150k = 0.42                    or the median of all the values. Thanks

Comment: @TimBenschop One simple way to get an aggregation over all customers is to remove the [Customer] field from the row shelf. If you're familiar with SQL, then Tableau typically performs aggregate calculations grouped by whatever discrete (blue) dimensions are in the visualization. Check the calculation. If it isn't what you want, you can then look at writing a table calculation. Those are powerful, but more complex, so I would first make sure you understand how simple and aggregate calculations work before learning about table calcs.

Comment: Tableau has introduced LOD calculations since this question was first posted, which provide a way to calculate measures aggregated at different levels of detail. You could use LOD calcs to compare the sum of Amount for each borrower against the avg sum of Amount for all borrowers.

Answer (score 3):

Let me know if you were going for something else, but if you are trying to simply visualize the data you can do this:

[image]

EDIT:

To create a calculated field go to: Analysis > Create Calculated Field, or select Create Calculated Field on one of the Data window title menu.

You can call that one SumAmount and the calculation would be:

```
sum([Amount])
```

Here is an example of what you can with calculated fields:

[image]

Here is a good guide: [How to Create a Calculated Field](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v6.1/public/online/en-us/i181532.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reaction! I don't only want to visualize, I want to make calculations with it. And I have over 30.000 "Customers" from which only 50% has more than 1 transaction. I have a total of 40.000 transactions over 30.000 customers and want to aggregate them. Do you get what I mean? I really appreciate your answer but I think it will not help me to calculate it. I think I have to create a new measure...